# How do I tell my employer for 2nd (or is it the 3rd) time that I no longer want to relocate?

Tags: professionalism, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior, europe, relocation

My employer has offices in multiple EU countries.

Two months ago I asked my employer to relocate. Initially at the end of the year. Then at end of September. They agreed and prepared a new contract. I signed the contract.

A few days later I changed my mind. I told HR. They accepted.

Two weeks later I changed my mind again. They agreed and prepared a new contract. I hesitated a few weeks. I asked for one amendment in the contract. They agreed. Eventually I signed. I also told HR that they can advise accounts and IT (IT needs to send me some equipment).

I don't know what I want.

The decision to relocate was spontaneous. I did no prior research. Only after signing the new contract I did research and discovered the complications involved. I loath complications (physical relocation, time pressure, bureaucratic, finding apartment, internet connection, utilities, new bank account, changing address for existing bank accountS). It's simpler staying.

Everytime I signed the new contract I regretted my decision. When I cancelled the contract I was relieved but not completely.I feel that I am making a mistake relocating. But I am not sure.

I do not know how the company (HR) will react if I tell them again that I changed my mind. The person in HR I spoke to was supportive and understanding. But I feel this is the straw that will break the camels back.

Should I accept the situation and relocate? (I could relocate back in 6 - 12 months time).
Should I tell HR?
How do I tell HR?

**My plan** Phone HR a ask them how bad it would be if I did not relocate, i.e. how much effort has the company done for this relocation. I would ask in person but most people are not working from the office.

(There is no need to remind me that my decision and behavior is unprofessional, naive, immature, chidlish, unplanned, thoughtless, stupid)

---

Other information (perhaps irrelevant)

1. Salary will be lower but cost of living lower too.
2. In the new location I would have to work from home (the company only has a *legal* office in the new location)
3. Time pressure. Once I arrive in the new location, I will only have a week to deal with all the complications I mentioned earlier.

---

**Update 1**
Reasons for wanting to relocate originally

1. The new country is / has: Less noisy. Lower population density. More space. Better accomodation. More reasonably priced accomodation.
2. I used to like the new location and its people. But that was what I thought of the place when visiting as a tourist.
3. I naively thought the grass is greener on the other side without thinking of details. It would be *cool* to leave. Its better there. Leave all the problems behind. (now I think I'm just going to take the problems with me)

Comment: Despite the title, it sounds like your real question is "what should I do?"... the answer to which is: make your own decision. We can't tell you what is best for your life.

Comment: @musefan sigh ... yes you are correct. This has caused me 2 months of worrying, swearing and sleepless nights. I need help.

Comment: Not an answer but you should definitely consider if "unprofessional, naive, immature, chidlish, unplanned, thoughtless, stupid" is enough to push them to get rid of you.  Depending on the specifics the new contract may override the old one and they might not be required to continue on with you if you break that one.  If you aren't following through on what you've agreed to, I would suggest contacting a labor lawyer to ensure you understand the impact of breaking this contract.

Comment: what were your reasons for wanting to relocate in the first place?

Comment: @AaronF I've added an update.

Comment: Six to 12 months isn't very long, really, especially if you're going to be working most of the time. You could go for six months or so and see whether you like it or not. If you don't then you can always move back. At least that way you would have tried it out. If you don't go then you might wonder "what if?" for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I feel this is the straw that will break the camels back.

I have to say this would be my fear too. Assuming you actually have any goodwill or credibility remaining with your employer changing your mind **again** can only erode that further. Every time you pull a 180 like this you're costing your employer time and effort - and *especially* now that you've told them to get the process in motion with IT etc.

I'm not saying you are stuck with the move now, actually, I *am* saying that, sort of. You've signed a contract, you've requested resources be allocated to you for this move. Yes they let you out of it before, but they weren't obligated to do so. If it helps - think of it as a trial period, you say you can relocate back in 6-12 months, which isn't exactly a huge commitment and if you hate it and come back I think it's a safe bet that "I tried it and it wasn't for me, I'm looking to move back" is going to be much, much better received than another 180 now.

Depending on local employment law they probably can't *fire* you over simply being indecisive like this, but it can sure as heck be extremely career limiting. Want to go for a promotion? **Nope**, @voyduyigne is unreliable and shows poor judgement and decision making skills. Want to transfer teams? **Nope**, @voyduyigne will likely change their mind in a few weeks and we'll have to re-jig everything *again*.

Look, this sort of vacillating over major life decisions is normal, I expect most people will do similar. But there's a smart way to do this - and that's by doing it all *before* you commit to it (which to all intents and purposes signing a contract is doing), hash it out with friends, family, your dog. But *only* sign actual legal contracts when you're reasonably confident that you've stopped flip-flopping.

Answer (score 9):

> Two months ago I asked my employer to relocate.

> A few days later I changed my mind.

> Two weeks later I changed my mind again.

### STOP.

You are making snap decisions without researching and thinking about them sufficiently. There is probably something deeper going on that is motivating you to jump around; you'll need to address this elsewhere as it is probably not a simple issue.

You should probably stay put, as it sounds like you're in no position to make a major decision. Give it another 3-6 months to detox from your indecision storm.

During the detox period, try this:

1. Identify the problem - why do you need/want to move? What are you trying to get away from or go in to?
2. Brainstorm several solutions to the problem. You can come up with at least 10†.
3. Take your list of solutions and evaluate each one for feasibility, cost, difficulty, uncertainty, etc.
4. Pick at least one
5. Do it.
6. Evaluate your situation. Still bad? Go back to 2 or 3.

### Limit your options

It is very easy to second-guess yourself if you have too many options. You can make it easier by limiting the number of options (only 1 or 2) and make a decision on those alone. See @captain-emacs's comment.

*Problematic:* what do you want for dinner?

*Better:* Do you want chicken cacciatore or fish tacos?

†Coming up with 10 solutions to a problem (or 10 examples of a thing) is a neat technique I learned long ago. It forces more out-of-the-box thinking.

Comment: +1 for "STOP". +100 for the rest. I knew an indecisive guy with indecision writ large. Whenevery we planned doing something with him involved, we ended up not doing anything. The only way of getting somewhere with him was to hide that there was a decision process involved. If both options are equally attractive, after research, throw a coin and strictly commit to it ahead of time.